# Spring data elasticsearch - Can't merge a non object mapping with an object mapping

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have an error, while trying to run my app with entity class:

```
@Document(indexName = "index", type = "event")
public class Event {

...

    @Field(type = FieldType.Date)
    private Date dateTime;

...

}
```

The error is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't merge a non object mapping [dateTime] with an object mapping [dateTime]
```

Why?

Ok, then I comment this `@Field` annotation. So, I'm having:

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: object mapping for [dateTime] tried to parse field [dateTime] as object, but found a concrete value
```

when I make

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type:application/json" http://localhost:8080/events -d '{ "dateTime": "2008-03-01T13:00:00.345"}'
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: No, just dropped it away.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a document with a GeoPoint property where instead of mapping the property with 'geo_point' it set type 'double' for both lat and long.
After struggling for some days I solved by defining the mapping:

```
if (!elasticsearchTemplate.indexExists(SEARCH_INDEX_NAME)) {
  elasticsearchTemplate.createIndex(SEARCH_INDEX_NAME);
}
elasticsearchTemplate.refresh(PlaceIndex.class);
elasticsearchTemplate.putMapping(PlaceIndex.class);
```

just before starting indexing items (and creating the index):

```
 for (Place place : placePage.getContent()) {
            IndexQuery indexQuery = new IndexQuery();

            PlaceIndex placeIndex = new PlaceIndex();

            placeIndex.setId(place.getId());
            placeIndex.setName(place.getName());
            placeIndex.setPosition(GeoPoint.fromPoint(new Point(place.getPosition().getY(),place.getPosition().getX())));


            indexQuery.setId(placeIndex.getId().toString());
            indexQuery.setObject(placeIndex);
            indexQuery.setSource(elasticObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(placeIndex));

            indexQuery.setIndexName(SEARCH_INDEX_NAME);
            indexQuery.setType(PLACE_INDEX_TYPE);

            queries.add(indexQuery);
            if (counter % INDEX_COMMIT_SIZE == 0) {
                elasticsearchTemplate.bulkIndex(queries);
                queries.clear();
            }
            counter++;
        }
```

It a bit late but I hope this help you or someone else.